# Laptop Adaptor Circuit Elements

Tags: power-supply, identification

Can you tell me about this circuit elements' name more specifically? Especially number 1 and 10; what are they?

[image]

[image]

[image: bottom circuit]

Number 1 text: SCC 068K275V-X2 MPXGMF 40/100/21

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the text from the right face of #1, and a photo of the bottom of the board so we can see how many pins each component has (and how the pins are arranged).

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design!

Comment: #10 is clearly a transformer.

Comment: We really need photos of all components with inscriptions in order to give a precise result. The rest could only be guesswork.

Comment: @android93  Out of curiosity.  What's the rated power of the power supply (it should be written on the plastic enclosure)?  What's the writing on the controller chip (the 8-pin chip on the green side of the board)?

Comment: @NickAlexeev it's 40 watt 2A*20V and the other one is "otcnkac uc3843al ea" something like that, its not readable. oh and this psu is fake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll bite:

1. X2 capacitor
2. Inductor
3. Fuse
4. Metal oxide varistor
5. Rectifier
6. Capacitor
7. Diode
8. Capacitor
9. Capacitor
10. Transformer
11. Power transistor
12. X1 capacitor
13. Optoisolator
14. Capacitor
15. Power transistor
16. Inductor
17. Capacitor
18. Transistor

Answer (score 1):

1 looks like a [X capacitor](http://www.kemet.com/kemet/web/homepage/kechome.nsf/file/KEMET%20Kollege%20Presentations/%24file/EvoxRifaRFIandSMD.pdf) (used for EMI/RFI filtering) and judging from a visible amount of copper, 10 most probably is a transformer.